# Merging more than two coluns in a DataFrame without replicating the Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem I am not sure how to solve: Imagine I have 3 different DataFrames:

df1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 |

df2:

| B | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | d1 | e1 |
| b4 | d4 | e4 |
| NaN | d5 | e5 |

df3:

| A | D | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a3 | d3 | f3 | g3 |
| NaN | d4 | f4 | g4 |
| NaN | d5 | f5 | g5 |

I want a way to merge these DataFrames into a single one, considering there is no column present in all of them, but there is always at least one column in commom between two of them. What I expect would be something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | e1 | NaN | NaN |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | NaN | f3 | g3 |
| NaN | b4 | NaN | d4 | e4 | f4 | g4 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | d5 | e5 | f5 | g5 |

I tried with pd.concat, but the result or duplicated columns or pasted the lines of a DataFrame below the other, not relating the columns the way I expected.

Comment: The merge you want is ambiguous, because you want to merge rows that (i) either match in multiple columns (e.g. in `A` and `B`); OR that match in only one (e.g. `A`) but has `B` as NaN.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a simpler way but:

After concating them, you could find the indexes of rows that contain matching values in each column.

```
df_m = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)

groups = (
   df_m.stack()
       .to_frame()
       .reset_index()
       .set_axis(['row', 'col', 'value'], axis=1)
       .groupby(['col', 'value'])
)
rows = groups.agg(tuple)[groups.count() > 1].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)['row'].explode()
```

`rows` before the explode:

```
0    (2, 6)
1    (0, 3)
2    (4, 7)
3    (5, 8)
Name: row, dtype: object
```

So rows `2, 6` need to be "combined", `0, 3`, etc.

One way to do this is to set their index to the same value and use `.groupby`

e.g. by turning it into `{ 2: 2, 6: 2, 0: 0, 3: 0, ... }`

We can then `.groupby().first()` to get each "combined" row:

```
idx = rows.groupby(level=0).transform('first').set_axis(rows)
idx = df_m.index.to_series().map(idx).fillna(df_m.index.to_series())

df.groupby(idx).first()
```

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G
0    a1    b1    c1    d1    e1  None  None
1    a2    b2    c2  None  None  None  None
2    a3    b3    c3    d3  None    f3    g3
4  None    b4  None    d4    e4    f4    g4
5  None  None  None    d5    e5    f5    g5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from functools import reduce
l = lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()][1]
df_out = reduce(lambda x, y: x.set_index(x.apply(l, axis=1)).combine_first(y.set_index(y.apply(l, axis=1))), [df1,df2,df3])

df_out
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G
1   a1   b1   c1   d1   e1  NaN  NaN
2   a2   b2   c2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   a3   b3   c3   d3  NaN   f3   g3
4  NaN   b4  NaN   b4   e4   f4   g4
5  NaN  NaN  NaN   d5   e5   f5   g5
```

Details, create a function that defines which row the values represent, ie `set_index`.  Then use `df.combine_first` to merge all the dataframes together on dataframe indexes and column headers.  With `functools.reduce` you can combine more that two dataframes.